# How to assign a value to each group by a groupby query on another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let the following dfs:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "k1": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "k2": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4],
    "v2": np.random.rand(7)
})

print(df1)
print("_______")
print(df2)
print("_______")
```

out:

```
   k1
0   1
1   1
2   2
3   2
4   3
5   3
6   4
7   4
8   4
_______
   k2        v2
0   1  0.260026
1   1  0.474951
2   2  0.695962
3   2  0.158575
4   3  0.396015
5   4  0.740344
6   4  0.293410
_______
```

I want to create a new column for `df1` such that for every key `k1`, a corresponding value will be applied such that if `k1` == `k2`, the value will be a function (say max) of `v2` of the group in `df2` whose key is `k2` (`k1`).

Required output for above case:

```
   k1  result
0   1  0.474951
1   1  0.474951
2   2  0.695962
3   2  0.695962
4   3  0.396015
5   3  0.396015
6   4  0.740344
7   4  0.740344
8   4  0.740344
```

It can be assumed that all keys present in `k1` are also in `k2`.

---

This is probably done with two groupby operations, one for query and one for assignment, but I can't figure out how to tie together the output of one to the input of the other.

---

Edit:
Please notice the example `k1` and `k2` are sorted for clarity, but are not guaranteed to be. I also don't want to sort because of `o(nlogn)` time, and this can be done in `o(n)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try `map` and `groupby`

```
df1['result'] = df1['k1'].map(df2.groupby('k2')['v2'].max())
```

---

```
   k1    result
0   1  0.474951
1   1  0.474951
2   2  0.695962
3   2  0.695962
4   3  0.396015
5   3  0.396015
6   4  0.740344
7   4  0.740344
8   4  0.740344
```

Comment: What enforces `k1` to be mapped by value to `k2`? It seems here like this relies on ordering, which fits the simple example data, but I am not sure solves the general case.

Comment: @Gulzar This approach doesn't rely on ordering. Pandas align data on indices and so does the `map` method so technically only the matching values of `k2` are mapped with `k1`

Comment: For improved performance we can pass an optional argument `sort=False` in the `groupby` call `df1['k1'].map(df2.groupby('k2', sort=False)['v2'].max())`

Comment: It works, but I fail to understand why. Neither `k1` nor `k2` are indices. This as far as I understand relies on the dataframe's indices to exist and to match. What am I missing?

Comment: @Gulzar when we group the dataframe `df2` by column `k2` and aggregate the column `v2` using `max` this operation automatically sets the index of aggregated column to `k2` then the mapping operation will automatically match the indices from the aggregated column and column values in `k1` of `df1`. Makes sense?

Comment: Now it makes sense, thanks! I asked about `max` as an example, but how would this be done with an arbitrary aggregation (using some lambda)?

Comment: @Gulzar If you want to apply arbitrary aggregation then we can use  `groupby` + `apply` so instead of `.max()` you can use `.apply(some_function)`

Comment: This came back to bite me, because I changed it a bit. What if I don't groupby, but only map? How to just map by `k1`->`df2[v2]` mapped by k2, no aggregation?

Comment: In that case we can do `df1['k1'].map(df2.set_index('k2')['v2])`, and just make sure that `df2` does not contain duplicates in `k2` column.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can sort on `k2` and `v2` columns in `df2` to ensure that the bigger value in column `v2` stay on first. Then drop duplicates on `k2` to keep the first which is the max. At last, `map` `v2` column in `k2` to `df1`.

```py
df1['result'] = df1['k1'].map(df2.sort_values(['k2', 'v2'], ascending=[True, False]).drop_duplicates('k2', keep='first').set_index('k2')['v2'])
```

```
print(df1)

   k1        result
0   1  0.303764
1   1  0.303764
2   2  0.026024
3   2  0.026024
4   3  0.213834
5   3  0.213834
6   4  0.757031
7   4  0.757031
8   4  0.757031
```